# Django-cms - CMS javascripts not being included on the frontend

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm creating a website with Django-Cms following the offcial [Introductory Tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.2/getting_started/tutorial.html#configuration-and-setup) and I'm having some issues with the edit-mode on the frontend. First of all, the top banner is not showing and the edit menus on the placeholders are all broken.
The first thing I did was to check for Javascript errors and quickly I found that the CMS scripts are not being included and initialized. Nothing is being generated for the {% render_block "js" %} tag.

I have searched the official documentation and user-lists on the web and I have found nothing about this issue.

**EDIT:**
Sekizai is working correctly, the problem seems to be with django-cms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some time to discover this and the documentation didn't mention it anywhere but from version 2.2 onwards a cms_toolbar django tag must be added within the  for the edit mode to work correctly.

Comment: The documentation is a bit sparse alright! They have a google group that is quite useful where you can get django-cms specific help quickly

Comment: Actually, I found the documentation to be quite extensive for version 2.2, but there are errors on parts of the documentation that were already written in previous versions.

Comment: Just to clarify  

{% cms_toolbar %} 

is the proper code, and it should go in your base.html file

Answer (score 1):

Note that the [tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.2/getting_started/tutorial.html) needs the following #*** tagged line of code for the edit menu to appear on the first page you make in the tutorial. I've informed the developers of this.

update: I was reading an old version of the tutorial.  [Here](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3.5/getting_started/tutorial.html) is the latest version.

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
      {% cms_toolbar %} #***
      {% render_block "css" %}
  </head>
  <body>

      {% placeholder base_content %}
      {% block base_content%}{% endblock %}
      {% render_block "js" %}
  </body>
</html>
```